# Wordpress/Wix + PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, html, css

I have been a web developer for some time now and in all the sites I do, I usually code the front-end with HTML from scratch. Gives me more customization and accessibility, but takes a lot of time to do so - not to mention making it responsive to mobiles. Are there any sites out there that could handle the front-end, but also at the same time can be fused together with PHP and MySQL as the back-end?

I already tried researching on utilizing Wordpress with PHP but somehow can't get a decent tutorial/information on how to fully do it. I encountered Adminer, it's good but not really close to PhpMyAdmin.

As of now, I mainly full-code the front-end in HTML. This is one of the samples (not the best, but just to give an idea)

```
<br/>

<!-- ==== Welcome Greetings ==== -->
<h1><?php echo $txt_homeheader.' '.$user_firstname.'!';?></h1>

<br/>

<!-- ==== Post Box ==== -->
<table border = 0>
<tr>
<td style = 'padding: 0vh;' >
    <center>
    <?php echo $txt_writepost;?>

    <br/><br/>

    <form action = '' method = 'post' id = 'form_home_post'>
        <textarea rows = '4' cols = '50' name = 'tb_post' form = 'form_home_post' placeholder='<?php echo $txt_postboxdesc;?>' required/></textarea>
        <br/><br/>
        <input type = 'submit' name = 'btn_postsubmit' value = 'Post'>
    </form>
    </center>
</td>
</tr>
</table>


<br/><br/>
<hr width = 40%>


<!-- ==== Post Box ==== -->
<h2><?php echo $txt_postsbanner;?></h2>
<br/>



<table border = 0 width = 40%>
<!-- ==== PHP ==== -->
<?php

    //Get all posts from DB
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY postdate DESC ";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        //Get Data from DB
        $postmsg = $row['postmsg'];
        $postowner = $row['postowner'];
        $postdate = $row['postdate'];

        $date = new DateTime($postdate);
        $formatted_date = $date->format("F d, Y h:i A");

        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
        $time_elapsed = timeago($postdate);

        //Search and match Post owner's id to users to get name
        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE profilecode = '$postowner' ";
        $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
        $user_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);

        $postowner_name = $user_row['firstname'].' '.$user_row['lastname'];

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo "<table width = 100% style = 'border: 1px black dashed; padding: 2vh; margin: 2vh;' ><tr><td>";
            echo "<ch1 style = 'font-size: 2vh;' >".$postowner_name."</ch1>";
            echo "<br/>";
            echo $time_elapsed.' | '.$formatted_date;
            echo "<br/><br/>";
            echo "<ch2 style = 'font-size: 3vh;' >".$postmsg."</ch2>";
            echo "</td></td></table>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }


?> 
<!-- ==== End PHP ==== -->
</table>

<br/><br/><br/><br/>


<!-- ==== INCLUDE FOOTER LANGUAGE TOGGLE ==== -->
<?php include('footer_language.php');?>

</center>
```

I wanted to have a click-and-drag front-end creator like Wix or Wordpress, and then later on modify its back-end code with PHP and MySQL.

For example:

`Click an empty 'Button' on the sidebar > Drag it to your site > Right click the newly created button > Modify Code > Insert your JS/PHP code or something...`

Is there anything like that?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: not really drag and drop, but plugins like elementor and wpbakery has some of the drag and drop, for PHP code, you can port it in functions.php like you normally would do

Comment: @Ghost yes, I tried Elementor previously. It's a decent plugin and I mainly use it for creating simple landing-page kind of sites that doesn't require database management and all that. Is that possible to fuse with PHP and MySQL?

Comment: wordpress has its own mysql interface wpdb object so it can definitely do mysql :)

Comment: @Ghost oh thanks! I'm really new in wp :D

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look Html5 drag and drop?

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("element", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("element"); // get the dragging element
  var dragged_element = document.getElementById(data);
  ev.target.appendChild(dragged_element);
  
  // display the data
  console.log(dragged_element);
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = dragged_element.getAttribute('src');
}
```

```css
#container-droppable {
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

  <p>Drag the image into the rectangle:</p>

  <div id="container-droppable" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  
  <br>
  
  <img id="drag1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">


  <p>URL IMAGE DRAGGED:</p>
  <div id="result"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

After that you can do an Ajax call to wordpress backend. There is a hook to catch that : https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins